# What is the value of a CMAttitude quaternion for absolutely no rotation

Tags: ios, iphone, matrix, quaternions, rotational-matrices

I have a saved rotation quaternion which depicts a specific rotation. I want all the other quaternion which I will get from my iPhone sensor to be transformed to the saved quaternion.

For that formula is sensorQuaternion * Inverse of savedQuaternion.

I want to save a quaternion with absolutely no rotation. What will be the x y z and w values of such quaternion?

Comment: According to [wikipedia] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), the quaternion that represents a rotation by 0 degrees is cos(0/2) + (i+j+k)sin(0/2) = 1 + 0 = 1. But I doubt this is a programming question... perhaps ask in a maths site?

Comment: No this is indeed a programming question.. Most of the gaming apps use Quaternion and Rotation matrix. In addition to this, apple has his own class CMAttitude which contains quaternion property.

Comment: Yes, you may be applying the quaternion representation of rotations in space to your game, but that is in no way tied to `ios`, the `iphone`, or programming in particular (at the very least, you could have mentioned the API CMAttitude in your question). I could post a similar question asking how to use a certain trigonometric formula in my game (for, say, easing animations...). In either case, I gave you the answer in my previous comment: `1 + 0i + 0j + 0k` (the identity).

Comment: But, Multiplying anything with the inverse of an identity will result in same equation ?

Comment: You want the _inverse_ of a given quaternion (different form zero rotation), so that when composed with what you have, it cancels out and gives no rotation?

Comment: Uh-oh, reading the Wikipedia article through, I think I gave you the formulas wrong.

Comment: Check this link: http://luaj.org/quaternions.html . Rotations are represented by unit-length quaternions, for which the multiplicative inverse (i.e., the one representing a rotation around the same axis of opposite angle) is equivalent to the conjugate (flip the sign of all imaginary components only).

Comment: So, if your rotation is represented by the quaternion with components (w, x, y, z) -w is the real part- you want the quaternion (w, -x, -y, -z).

Comment: again inverse of [1, 0, 0, 0] will be [1, 0, 0, 0] and multiplying any quaternion with this will give the same result :(.. Or i am not getting it :((

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85397/discussion-between-nicolasmiari-and-grisleyb).